# Python OpenVPN-API installation successful but 'openvpn.Client()' raises AttributeError

Tags: python, openvpn

I have installed the openvpn-api library correctly, but for some reason, the `openvpn.Client()` function is not recognized. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

What could be causing the "AttributeError: module 'openvpn' has no attribute 'Client'" error when trying to run OpenVPN with the openvpn-api library installed?

Here is the code I am using:

```
import openvpn
import time

# Path to the OpenVPN configuration file
config_path = 'C:\\Users\\OpenVPN\\my_vpn_config.ovpn'

# Initialize OpenVPN client
vpn = openvpn.Client()

# Load configuration file
vpn.load_config(config_path)

# Connect to VPN server
vpn.connect()

# Wait for the connection to establish
while True:
    status = vpn.status()
    if status.state == 'CONNECTED':
        print('Connected to', status.remote_address)
        break
    time.sleep(1)

# Disconnect from VPN server
vpn.disconnect()
```

Comment: @python_user i use openvpn-api and openvpn_api get same error

Answer (score 0):

Use it

```
from openvpn_api import VPN
# Configuração do cliente OpenVPN
client = VPN('127.0.0.1', 1194)

# Start VPN connection
client.connect()

# Print connection information
print('Tunnel IP address:', client.get_virtual_ip())
print('Tunnel subnet mask:', client.get_virtual_netmask())

# Send data through the tunnel
client.send('Hello, world!')

# Receive data from the tunnel
data = client.recv()

# Close the VPN connection
client.disconnect()
```